# C or C++ compiler for the Tandy 1000 PC SX?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have my dad's old PC from the 1980's. It's a Tandy 1000 PC SX:

This computer doesn't have a modem, but I have another PC that has Windows XP on it and it also has a 5 3/4 inch floppy drive. So where can I find a C/C++ compiler for this old PC?

Comment: Hey have you made a C program compile/run on that machine ? Would be curious to see how long does it takes !

Comment: Sadly no, the machine was water damaged about 5 years ago. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my God, I haven't seen one of those in forever.  Okay, that's running a version of MS/DOS, no later than about MS/DOS 3 as I recall.

First thing is to make sure you can read and write a floppy on the XP computer that the Tandy will read.

You'll need to look for a fairly old version of Turbo C, even, I'd guess.  You probably should look into the [Tiny C Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler).

Comment: You might be able to use laplink to transfer data from your new pc if it has a serial or parallel port

Comment: Does Tiny C Compiler support DOS?

Comment: @rakslice it did (MS/DOS and DOS are the same thing). Can't say what it supports now.

Comment: @CharlieMartin ah, cool, I saw Windows support mentioned on the TCC page but not MS- or any other DOS

Answer (score 4):

YOu might be able to use [Turbo C 2.01](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/tc201). I could when I had a Tandy 1000HX.

Comment: Turbo C FTW!  It's one of the niftiest DOS IDEs I've ever seen.  And it compiles really quickly.

Answer (score 4):

[Tandy 1000-series FAQ](http://www.oldskool.org/guides/tvdog/1kfaq.html)

[III.G.2. What C compilers will work on my Tandy 1000?](http://www.oldskool.org/guides/tvdog/1kfaq.html#III.G.2)

Answer (score 2):

[Check this out.](http://www.oldskool.org/guides/tvdog/1kfaq.html#III.G.2)

But I have to say, if you're really going hardcore old school, you need to code in assembler.

Comment: This is going to be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Enjoy.  I used PowerC when I was in college.  Ahhhh, the good old days!

Comment: @John Dibling: Assembly, are you crazy? I'd rather program in GW-BASIC.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to program for this thing for the first place?
I guess [borland C/ Turbo C](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/tc201) should prabably work on it.

There is apparently also a [Turbo C++.](https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/tcpp101)
And [here's another](http://www.uv.tietgen.dk/staff/mlha/Download/dos/#Borland) source for various such things.

Comment: Dude this thing is vintage. Plus I want to make some cool games for it.

Comment: "Why would you want to program for this thing for the first place?"  Are you sure you're a programmer?

Comment: Also your answer doesn't work as Windows wasn't invented yet and the link you provided was for Windows 3.1. I need a compiler for DOS.

Comment: It says windows but these should also work for DOS. you can confirm that using DOSBox.

Comment: Also, I would understand the vintage value if that was a cool Amiga or even a Commador 64 but a tandy PC? pffft.

Comment: @shoosh: Well I'm sorry I don't have a Commador 64 lying around. Listen this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The [Digital Mars C++ compiler](http://www.digitalmars.com/) claims to still support 16-bit DOS and Win16.

I'm not sure if the compiler itself will run on those platforms or if you'd have to 'cross compile" on a Win32 system and copy the results to the Tandy.

Actually, I'm not sure it works at all, but the support claim is pretty prominent.

The nice thing about going with Digital Mars is that you'd be able to use a much more modern compiler than the old Turbo C/C++ that's freely available.  I imagine that template and STL support is much better in Digital Mars than in the old Borland compilers.

Though, the old Borland stuff might have better out of the box UI frameworks and such or  old DOS source code that you dig up might actually work better with the old compiler.

Comment: for what it's worth, DMC is the current version of Symantec C++, and that was formally known as Zortech C/C++ and that actually ran on the Tandy

Answer (score 0):

I would totally go for Turbo C that others have mentioned on here.  They are very fast, easy to use, and in general have made me happy when coding in DOS.

PS:  How do you plan to get Turbo C from the internet onto your machine?  Via a terminal file transfer over serial port?

Answer (score 0):

Given the restrictions on that old computer you might want to use your other PC to cross compile for the Tandy 1000 PC SX. If you are using Linux the it's easy to build a cross compiler for DOS with Dan Kegel's [crosstool](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/).